# Restoring database - How to keep replication in place

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

Server A: have two databases - DB1(Publisher) and DB2(Subscriber)
Replication is currently working fine for these two databases.

Server B: have two databases - DB1(Publisher) and DB2(Subscriber)
Replication is currently working fine for these two databases.

Now, due to some testing issues, I want to restore copy of DB1(Publisher) from Server1 to Server2.
But I am concerend about replication.

What is best way to keep the replication in-place on Server2?

I am thinking to follow these steps -

- Take backup of database DB1 from Server1
- Disable all the *associated* SQL Server Agent Jobs on DB1, DB2 on Server2
- Restore Database DB1 on Server2 from back in step# 1
  (do I need to go for option WITH KEEP_REPLICATION ??)
- Enable SQL Server Agent Jobs on DB1, DB2 on Server2

Can please guide if these steps seems okay?

Answer (score 3):

see below how I successfully restore a replication (transactional replication).

```
1 - I script everything related to that publication - so that I can create it again from those scripts if things go wrong
2 - I script all the user and permissions in the database I want to restore (if the backup comes   from a different environment/server)
3 - disable any processes that hit the database you want to restore
4 - backup the current database
5 - restore verifyonly the backup you have just created (in case you need to restore it)
6 - see if you have enough disk space
7 - check if the database is involved in replication



---------------------------------------
--> 5 - see if the database is involved in replication (transactional replication)
---------------------------------------
SELECT 
name as [Database name],
CASE is_published 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
    ELSE 'Yes' 
    END AS [Is Published],
CASE is_merge_published 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
    ELSE 'Yes' 
    END AS [Is Merge Published],
CASE is_distributor 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
    ELSE 'Yes' 
    END AS [Is Distributor],
CASE is_subscribed 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
    ELSE 'Yes' 
    END AS [Is Subscribed]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4
go



use DB1
go
-- at the DB1 database
declare @db sysname
select @db = 'DB1'
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ( @db, 'IsSyncWithBackup' )
--0

--change the value to TRUE
sp_replicationdboption @dbname= 'DB1',
                   @optname= 'sync with backup',
                   @value='true'


--=====================================================================================
-- THE RESTORE
-- note the backup of the tail of the transaction log alongside the restore.
-- note also the KEEP_REPLICATION option
--=====================================================================================


USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE [DB1] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
BACKUP LOG [DB1] TO  DISK = N'F:\SQLBackups\UserDB\DB1\SQLAPPLON1_the_tail_log.trn' WITH     NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'tail log backup', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 1

RESTORE DATABASE [DB1] FROM  DISK =   N'F:\SQLBackups\UserDB\DB1\SQLAPPLON1_DB1_FULL_20140909_222917.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'DB1' TO N'E:\SQLData\DB1.mdf', 
 MOVE N'DB1_log' TO N'E:\SQLLogs\DB1_log.ldf',  
 KEEP_REPLICATION,  
 NOUNLOAD,  
 REPLACE,  STATS = 1
 go

ALTER DATABASE [DB1] SET MULTI_USER
GO
--=====================================================================================
-- THE RESTORE - FINISH
--=====================================================================================



---------------------------------------
-- set sync with backup to false (unless decided otherwise)
-- problem with this is that it slows the log reader a bit

use DB1
go
-- at the DB1 database
declare @db sysname
select @db = 'DB1'
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ( @db, 'IsSyncWithBackup' )
--1

--change the value to False
sp_replicationdboption @dbname= 'DB1',
                       @optname= 'sync with backup',
                       @value='FALSE'

-- at the DB1 database
declare @db sysname
select @db = 'DB1'
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ( @db, 'IsSyncWithBackup' )
--0


---------------------------------------
--Script to Enable/Disable Database for Replication
use master
exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = 'DB1',
@optname = 'publish',
@value = 'True'
go



---------------------------------------
-- There were some problems
-- the backup that I needed to use to restore the DB was much older and from a different server


-- I used these two commands
-- from inside the DB1 database (in the publisher)

use DB1
go

DBCC OPENTRAN 
sp_replrestart

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174390.aspx

--sp_replrestart is an internal replication stored procedure and s
--hould only be used when restoring a database published in a transactional replication 
--topology as directed in the topic Strategies for 
--Backing Up and Restoring Snapshot and Transactional Replication.

--Used by transactional replication during backup and restore so that 
--the replicated data at the Distributor is synchronized with data at the Publisher. 
--This stored procedure is executed at the Publisher on the publication database.

--How if works? 
--sp_replrestart will fill NO-OP (No-Operation) transaction which will cause the 
--LSN's to increase until the log LSN matches the LSN as per Distribution database. 
--So from there-on, Logreader agent will be able to read the LSN, it is expecting.

--Note: Depending on how old the backup of the Published database which was restored, 
--it may take hours for this operation and may make the transaction log to grow big.
--and grow by gigs, until they match.



--=====================================================================================
-- THE TEST
-- I add the folowing table to the published database
-- then I add the article to the publication
-- start a snapshot
-- and check if the article is in the subscription
-- when I generated the SNAPSHOT - it only generate this ONE ARTICLE
--=====================================================================================

use DB1
go
--DROP TABLE dbo.marcelo_test

create table dbo.marcelo_test(
i int not null identity(1,1) not for replication
,the_name varchar(40) not null )

insert into marcelo_test values ('belluno')
insert into marcelo_test values ('rovigo')
insert into marcelo_test values ('feltre')
insert into marcelo_test values ('cremona')
insert into marcelo_test values ('padova')
insert into marcelo_test values ('vicenza')
insert into marcelo_test values ('venezia')


select * from dbo.marcelo_test

alter table dbo.marcelo_test
add constraint pk_marcelo primary key clustered (i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you restore a backup of a replicated database to another server or database, replication settings cannot be preserved.  In this case you will need to recreate all publications and subscriptions after the backup is restored.  See the section *Restoring Databases Involved in Replication* in [Strategies for Backing Up and Restoring Snapshot and Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152560.aspx).